# Why hook_preprocess_html() isn't working?

Tags: 7, hooks

Why `hook_preprocess_html()` isn't firing in my module file? Is it only works in theme_hook?

EDIT:

```
function my_module_preprocess_html(&$variables) { 
  if (current_path() == 'user') { 
    $variables['head_title'] = implode(' | ', array(drupal_get_title(),  variable_get('site_name'))); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: can you provide more info please? Some piece of code from module file and theme file

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer 
`function my_module_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  if (current_path() == 'user') {

    $variables['head_title'] = implode(' | ', array(drupal_get_title(), 
variable_get('site_name')));

  }

}`

Comment: You cleared cache and put an exit or debug statement in? How can you tell it isn't hitting that function?

Answer (score 1):

Try the general preprocess hook, like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess().
 */
function my_module_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'html') {}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work too.

Comment: can you show your module file structure, list all files you created, and name the file you have the above code in. what's your module name ? is your module enabled ?